# How to turn off the beep sound in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder

On Mac OS X, I am running Flex Builder (which is basically a customized Eclipse). When I do a Find it beeps if it cannot find the selected text and when it wraps the search to the top.

Is it possible to turn off that beep? I've searched the internet and the preferences pane to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to bypass Eclipse default "run beep" on windows, by setting setting the "beep" sound to a silent .wav file

Comment: Yes, on Windows go to Control Panel->Change System Sounds.  Change the "Default Beep"

Answer (score 5):

You can get rid of it by turning down the alert volume system-wide in the Mac OS sound preferences (Sound -> Sound Effects -> Alert volume).

Comment: Best answer for Mac OS here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you can disable this same (annoying) beep by blacklisting the pcspkr module.

None of these are solutions to the problem, however.  To disable alert beeps system-wide is probably not what a person wants to do when they ask how to disable them in one specific application for one specific function.

If my smoke alarm keeps annoying me when I'm cooking then I can disconnect it, but that's probably not the best solution...

Comment: Okay... but how do I blacklist the pcspkr module?

Comment: Create a file in /etc/modprobe.d/ called something like "blacklist-pcspkr.conf" and put a line in it that says:

blacklist pcspkr

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running some kind of X Windows derivative, run these two commands from an terminal:

- `xset b off`
- `xset b 0 0 0`

You may add these to your `.xinitrc` or `.bashrc` to guarantee disabling on each system restart.

[Original Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=126746)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, compared to the one that changes the 'beep' sound to a silent .wav file.

**Settings -> System -> Sound -> App volume and device preferences (Scroll all the way down) -> System Sounds -> Slide it to 0**

I am on Windows 10, and it worked for me. I had a beep sound whenever I typed = when assigning something to a variable.