# How can I disable the annoying clicking sounds in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm using PyDev within Apatana Studio 3, and I noticed whenever files are updated in the project directory (ie. when the package explorer is refreshed), there is an annoying virtual clicking sound. Since my project is generating files rather slowly, I get several clicking sounds each time I debug it.

So, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to Eclipse and not really Aptana Studio 3 (so, take a look at: [How to turn off the beep sound in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331757/how-to-turn-off-the-beep-sound-in-eclipse))